# how can I automatically generate slug for user OneToOneField url

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am building a django application that requires users to sign in and have profiles that other users should be able to view but I am stuck at generating unique slug urls for each user. I want a user to be redirected to myexample.com/elon-musk instead of my-example.com/profile so that every user profile page can be unique.Any ideas on how I can go about it? Thanks In advance.

```
   models.py
class ContractorProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name= 'profile',)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(null=True, blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if slug is None:
        slug = slugify(self.user)
        while self.__class__.objects.filter(slug=slug).exists():
            slug = "%s-%s" % (slug,str(uuid.uuid4())[:5])
            self.slug = slug
        super(ContractorProfile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

```
   views.py

   @login_required
def dynamic_lookup_view(request, user):
    obj = ContractorProfile.objects.get(user=user)
    return render (request, "CsignTest/profile.html", {"obj": obj})
```

```
   urls.py

re_path(r'^profile/(?P<user>\w+)/$', CsignTest_views.dynamic_lookup_view, name='user-prof'),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you missed the self and generate the slug from the user name because it is unique

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.slug is None:
         self.slug = slugify(self.user.username)
    super(ContractorProfile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

hope this helps and for the admin try this

```
from . models import your_model
from django.contrib import admin

class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    prepopulated_fields = {"slug": ("title",)} 

admin.site.register(your_modelname,ArticleAdmin)
```

this should work because the Username is exist in the django User model

Comment: thanks your solution helps although in the admin page it registers the slug as a digit. Any idea on how I can generate the slug from the user input username?

Comment: Good ^_^ , happy coding and do not forget to check my answer as useful and as the best answer

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a prepopulate field in admin.py like this

```
from . models import your_model
from django.contrib import admin

class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    prepopulated_fields = {"slug": ("title",)} 

admin.site.register(your_modelname,ArticleAdmin)
```

Comment: How can I implement this in my user model.I've used CustomUserAdmin in place of ArticleAdmin and user in place of title but it hasn't changed. When I try to hardcode the url I get this error ```invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'newuser'
```